# Replace quotes inside quoted string with escaped quotes in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ to find `(".*)"(.*)` and replace it with `\1\"\2` but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know why.

Example:
`Someone said "My name is "sean""`
I want it to be:
`Someone said "My name is \"sean\""`

Edit: In my case the closing quote is always on the end of line so will `(".*)"(.*"$)` work?

Edit2: Also the first quote is preceded with a comma so I will use `(,".*)"(.*"$)` though it may not work in some cases but I think it will work with my file.

Now there is the problem with the replace it doesn't add `\"` it just add some space.

Comment: Is that possible? What about this: `"abc","123"` vs. `"the following character "," is called a comma"`? How do you know where one value ends and another begins?

Comment: What about if i made it like this (".*)"(.*"$)  ? where dollar means end of line.

Comment: Then you have more specific requirements, and you need to edit your question to explain that. But that doesn't help you either: `I asked "why?", they said "escaped characters!"`

Comment: Sorry for not specifying my requirements but though it may not work in all cases but I think it will work in the file I am using. Anyway I am having the problem with the replace it doesn't add \" it just add some space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work... you just need to do a little fixing...

The **Find what** regex should be `("[^"]*)("\w*)(")([^"]*")`
The **Replace with** expression should be `\1\\\2\\\3\4`

Make sure you select the Search Mode to be "Regular expression"

**Explanation...**

This is quite tricky - I've assumed that the quoted text WITHIN quotes is just a single word. If you assume something else it becomes very hard to pin down.

You need to find a
`"` followed by
`[^"]*` - any number of characters that are NOT a `"` and then
`("\w*)(")` - a quoted word, and then finally
`([^"]*")` - any additional number of non-quote characters + a final quote

This is important because regular expression matching is greedy by default, and a `.*` would continue to match all characters, including `"` until the end of the string (see [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) )

In the replacement string you need to have `\\` to represent a single `\`

Comment: When I used it it added escape character to all quotes. Could you explain briefly this regex for me?

Comment: Hello again - @Cloules I've re-read the question a bit more closely, and updated the regex and replacement accordingly. Note the caveat though. I've had to assume just a single word within the quotes.

Comment: I ended up using (,".*)([^\\])"(.*"$) replacing it with \1\2\\"\3 but thanks your answer helped me understand the problem better. My answer needed me to repeat the replace but it is not problem for me. D:

Comment: ok cool & happy to help. Glad you've found something that works now - although I might still be tempted to replace the instances of `.*` in your expression with `[^"]*`, but I guess with the end-of-line anchor (`$`) its not so important